# Subfigures are not aligned well

Tags: subfig

Below I have 4 subfigures, but I have a problem if the third subfigure text exceeded one line, the 4th figure will shift down a little bit as you see below. Not sure how to fix this please?

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\title{AlgorithmTemplate}
% \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\include{pythonlisting}

\begin{document}

sa

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{testfig.png}
        \caption{a}
        \label{fig: a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{testfig.png}
        \caption{b  }
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{testfig.png}
        \caption{I have some text here that will shift the 4th figure to bottom}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{testfig.png}
        \caption{d}
        \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{d}
    \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change all `[b]`s to `[t]` at `subfigure`s. Also, remove the middle `\hfill` and leave an empty space. This will create a new paragraph and move other two figures to the next line. You might need to add an extra vertical space, e.g. `\bigskip` or `\vspace{v-sep}`, where vsep could any length s.a. 12pt, 1cm etc.

Comment: Note that [t] means the first baseline, which is at the bottom of the image.  You can use `\hfill\llap{\rule{\textwdith}{0.4pt}}` to show the baseline location.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Thanks. I got error, `Undefined control sequence. \hfill\llap{\rule{\textwdith}{0.4pt}}`. Where I should add this please? Should I add it just before `\end{figure}`?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  wdith should be width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bottom alignment `[b]` to the top `[t]` at each `\subfigure`. Then, if you want to have a grid of 4x4 images, remove the middle `\hfill` and add an empty space. This is will move the other 2 figures to the next line. You might need to increase a vertical spacing. Therefore, use `\vspace{...}` with any length s.a. `12pt`, `1cm` etc. or `\bigskip`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\title{AlgorithmTemplate}
% \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\include{pythonlisting}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{a}
        \label{fig: a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{b  }
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \bigskip%
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{I have some text here that will shift the 4th figure to bottom}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{d}
        \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main}
    \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\kant[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add more about the difference between `[t]` (top) and `[b]` (bottom) please?

Comment: These options determine a vertical alignment of an object w.r.t. a surrounding environment, with `[c]` being usually the default (See the _special notes on the pos parameter_ on [LaTeX/Boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes)). If e.g. you place a tabular in a paragraph and add the option `[t]`, LaTeX will position the table such that a baseline of its topmost part (text, rule etc.) is aligned with a baseline of a paragraph. The link has more detailed explanation of those concepts.

Comment: It's worth noting that macros/environments such as `tabular`, `subfigure`, `minipage`, `parbox` etc. can contain other elements with their own baselines. The positional options are available to instruct LaTeX where the main baseline is going to be. Hence, `[t]` or `[b]` would refer to the topmost or the bottom-most element, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. The `baseline` though is not defined in the document. I am not sure what it does mean exactly?

Comment: Each element in latex is a box, which latex place in a sequence. Each box has a baseline; it's a property. This is not necessarily a bottom point of a box: baseline of `p`, `g` etc. is  set slightly upwards to gain depth and compensate for the bottom parts. When LaTeX places `h` and `g` next to each other, it aligns them along baselines, so it knows a box of `g` needs to be slightly lowered to correctly line up two letters or their baselines. Try the link I provided.